# Are rectifiable curves locally convex (or concave)?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis, curves

I have a geometry project coming up, and have stumbled on the following problem, wondering if anybody had some help to offer. 
Let $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ be a rectifiable curve. I.e the following value is finite
$$L(\gamma)=sup_{\sigma\in P}\sum_{i=1}^{n}||\gamma(x_{i+1})-\gamma(x_i)||$$
Where P is the set of subdivisions of the unit interval.

I want to show (or find a counterexample) that then $\gamma$ is locally convex or concace, i.e $\forall x\in [0,1]$ there exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\gamma|_{[x-\delta, x+\delta]}$ is either convex or concave.

Comment: what about $\sqrt{x}$ on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @DavideMaran Yeah, good point, modified my question to be clearer, to ask whether there always is a neighborhood where the function is either convex or concave (i.e doesn't change infinitely between the two)

Comment: Question.  What does it mean for a function with values in $\mathbb R^2$ to be "convex"?  Can you answer the simpler case of $\mathbb R$?  That is, if a function $\gamma : [-1,1]\to \mathbb R$ has bounded variation, is there a neighborhood of $(0,0+\delta)$ where it is either convex or concave?